# When screen capturing frames in two videos of different frame rates do I need to use variable frame rate

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame-rate

When looping through frames in two videos side by side I’m stuck on a problem of having inconsistent frame rates generated in the final video.

I’m taking a screenshot frame by frame in a browser and using a for loop to generate each frame.

If I’m programming the loop to take 25 screenshots per second I am getting laggy frames on some videos that are way above 25-30fps ie 60fps

Do I need to program it to start taking 60 screenshots instead once I start scanning the 60fps video?

Comment: Why not just capture at 60? How is ffmpeg involved?

Comment: I am buffering the frames to ffmpeg for encoding. I am taking the total duration in seconds * 25 to figure out how many frames to take. When I move it to 60 FPS then the lower frame rate clips go into slow motion.

Comment: Ideally capturing would be uniform. However I’ve built an editor and users can upload any frame rate